# Disable logging of .ajax() in Umbrella.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, umbrellajs

I'm trying out Umbrella.js as a simple alternative to jQuery. I have an `.ajax()` call to retrieve some content and when the method is run there's a `console.log()` displaying the request object - with `body`, `headers,`method` and the request URL.

Viewing the log in Chrome's inspector shows the log is coming from Umbrella.js. This is using umbrella.min.js@2.6.5.

Is there a way to disable logging?

Comment: edit umbrella.js - remove the console log from `e.response;return c(a,b,e)}),console.log(b,b.method,a),e.open(b.method,a)` ... i.e. that fragment should end up `e.response;return c(a,b,e)}),e.open(b.method,a)`

Comment: It's awkward, in source code there are no console logs https://github.com/umbrellajs/umbrella/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=console

Comment: if you're using the CDN version, then ask the author to remove it

Comment: @here - I noticed it was removed in the newest release. It's present in v2.6.5 and below, removed in 2.6.6. The CDN was serving v2.6.5.